# Teaching the CNN with Keras : How to read csv dataset using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, dataset

I have created the dataset I need for my project using:

http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/via-1.0.6.html

When I've exported the dataset in csv format I got the following table containing these attributes:

```
[#filename] [file_size] [file_attributes] [region_count] [region_id] [region_shape_attributes] [region_attributes]
```

I've loaded the dataset using:

```
from pandas import read_csv
dataset = read_csv("dataset.csv")
```

Now I do not know which column attributes I need to pass to dataset.

These are the type of values for the columns:

```
[#filename]               [0.jpg][1.jpg]...[1000.jpg]
[file_size]               [74709][74709]...[63595]
[file_attributes]         [{}][{}]...[{}]
[region_count]            [5][2]...[16]
[region_id]               [0][1][0][2]...[1]
[region_shape_attributes] ["name":"polygon","all_points_x":[319, 496...]
[region_attributes]       ["object type":"cat"]...["object type":"cat"]
```

What should I load to Keras?

If I were to say:

```
cnn = Sequential()
.
.
.
cnn.fit(data, label, ...)
```

What is my data from the table? I need [#filename] to tell the Keras where to look for images, don't I? Then, how do I tell the keras the points where my object is located? I presume that is [region_shape_attributes]?

How would I concentrate this into data field needed for training the neural network?

I trust the label I can use is from the [region_attribute] field, but I am not sure how to pass dataset to Keras, so I need help.

Comment: well, doing machine learning is first and foremost understanding your data and what you want to do with them. So I am not sure we can really help you here.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, Machine learning isn't just coding! so you need to learn what it is and how different algorithms work.

So now stop coding! and then go to the www.coursera.org and look for Andrew Ng's ML class.

after that, you have some basic understandings of ML algorithms and then you can start coding and learning more!